Why is json server not getting other items in the object i'm trying to fetch
I opened a json-server to serve my data so I can get data from it as my endpoints but whenever I try to get other items in the object, it always returns the first item of the object regardless of the one I'm trying to hit at. I have tried different ideas but it keeps returning the first item of the list.
My json file:
{
  "growthData": [
    {
      "name": "January",
      "users": 1070,
      "uv": 1200,
      "pv": 800,
      "growthRate": 0,
      "activeUsers": 790,
      "percentActive": 30
    },
    {
      "name": "February",
      "users": 8580,
      "uv": 1800,
      "pv": 1400,
      "growthRate": 80,
      "activeUsers": 6800,
      "percentActive": 34.6
    },
    {
      "name": "March",
      "users": 2200,
      "uv": 2500,
      "pv": 2000,
      "growthRate": 46.67,
      "activeUsers": 1870,
      "percentActive": 37.0
    },
    {
      "name": "April",
      "users": 3274,
      "uv": 3400,
      "pv": 2700,
      "growthRate": 36.36,
      "activeUsers": 1578,
      "percentActive": 39.3
    },
    {
      "name": "May",
      "users": 2583,
      "uv": 4500,
      "pv": 3600,
      "growthRate": 23.12,
      "activeUsers": 1406,
      "percentActive": 43.1
    },
    {
      "name": "June",
      "users": 5290,
      "uv": 5800,
      "pv": 4700,
      "growthRate": 30,
      "activeUsers": 2780,
      "percentActive": 50.0
    },
    {
      "name": "July",
      "users": 6807,
      "uv": 7500,
      "pv": 6000,
      "growthRate": 30.77,
      "activeUsers": 4260,
      "percentActive": 52.5
    },
    {
      "name": "August",
      "users": 8808,
      "uv": 9700,
      "pv": 7800,
      "growthRate": 29.41,
      "activeUsers": 3572,
      "percentActive": 56.5
    },
    {
      "name": "September",
      "users": 11507,
      "uv": 12800,
      "pv": 10300,
      "growthRate": 30.68,
      "activeUsers": 9723,
      "percentActive": 58.7
    }
  ],

  "totalStreamsData": [
    {
      "month": "January",
      "streams": 150000,
      "peakStreams": 45000,
      "averageStreamsPerDay": 5000,
      "growthRate": 0,
      "isGrowthPositive": false
    },
    {
      "month": "February",
      "streams": 200000,
      "peakStreams": 60000,
      "averageStreamsPerDay": 7150,
      "growthRate": 33.33,
      "isGrowthPositive": true
    },
    {
      "month": "March",
      "streams": 250000,
      "peakStreams": 70000,
      "averageStreamsPerDay": 8000,
      "growthRate": 25.00,
      "isGrowthPositive": true
    },
    {
      "month": "April",
      "streams": 180000,
      "peakStreams": 50000,
      "averageStreamsPerDay": 6000,
      "growthRate": -28.00,
      "isGrowthPositive": false
    },
    {
      "month": "May",
      "streams": 300000,
      "peakStreams": 90000,
      "averageStreamsPerDay": 9700,
      "growthRate": 66.67,
      "isGrowthPositive": true
    },
    {
      "month": "June",
      "streams": 350000,
      "peakStreams": 100000,
      "averageStreamsPerDay": 11667,
      "growthRate": 16.67,
      "isGrowthPositive": true
    },
    {
      "month": "July",
      "streams": 400000,
      "peakStreams": 110000,
      "averageStreamsPerDay": 13000,
      "growthRate": 14.29,
      "isGrowthPositive": true
    },
    {
      "month": "August",
      "streams": 450000,
      "peakStreams": 125000,
      "averageStreamsPerDay": 14500,
      "growthRate": 12.50,
      "isGrowthPositive": true
    },
    {
      "month": "September",
      "streams": 500000,
      "peakStreams": 130000,
      "averageStreamsPerDay": 15500,
      "growthRate": 11.11,
      "isGrowthPositive": true
    }
  ],

  "users": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "John Doe", "active": true },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Jane Doe", "active": false },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Alex Smith", "active": true },
    { "id": 4, "name": "Emily Johnson", "active": false },
    { "id": 5, "name": "Michael Brown", "active": true },
    { "id": 6, "name": "Sarah Davis", "active": true },
    { "id": 7, "name": "David Wilson", "active": false },
    { "id": 8, "name": "Emma Martinez", "active": true },
    { "id": 9, "name": "Chris Taylor", "active": false },
    { "id": 10, "name": "Olivia Anderson", "active": true }
  ],
  "streams": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "songName": "Song A",
      "artist": "Artist X",
      "dateStreamed": "2023-09-01",
      "streamCount": 1000,
      "userId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "songName": "Song B",
      "artist": "Artist Y",
      "dateStreamed": "2023-09-01",
      "streamCount": 1500,
      "userId": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "songName": "Song C",
      "artist": "Artist Z",
      "dateStreamed": "2023-09-02",
      "streamCount": 2000,
      "userId": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "songName": "Song D",
      "artist": "Artist W",
      "dateStreamed": "2023-09-02",
      "streamCount": 2500,
      "userId": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "songName": "Song E",
      "artist": "Artist V",
      "dateStreamed": "2023-09-03",
      "streamCount": 3000,
      "userId": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "songName": "Song F",
      "artist": "Artist U",
      "dateStreamed": "2023-09-03",
      "streamCount": 3500,
      "userId": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "songName": "Song G",
      "artist": "Artist T",
      "dateStreamed": "2023-09-04",
      "streamCount": 4000,
      "userId": 7
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "songName": "Song H",
      "artist": "Artist S",
      "dateStreamed": "2023-09-04",
      "streamCount": 4500,
      "userId": 8
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "songName": "Song I",
      "artist": "Artist R",
      "dateStreamed": "2023-09-05",
      "streamCount": 5000,
      "userId": 9
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "songName": "Song J",
      "artist": "Artist Q",
      "dateStreamed": "2023-09-05",
      "streamCount": 5500,
      "userId": 10
    }
  ],
  "revenue": [
    { "source": "Subscriptions", "amount": 50000 },
    { "source": "Ads", "amount": 15000 },
    { "source": "Merchandise", "amount": 12000 },
    { "source": "Partnerships", "amount": 8000 },
    { "source": "Events", "amount": 7000 },
    { "source": "Sponsorships", "amount": 6000 },
    { "source": "Donations", "amount": 3000 },
    { "source": "Licensing", "amount": 4000 },
    { "source": "Royalties", "amount": 2500 },
    { "source": "Affiliate", "amount": 2000 }
  ],
  "songs": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "Song A", "artist": "Artist X", "streams": 10000 },
    { "id": 2, "title": "Song B", "artist": "Artist Y", "streams": 8500 },
    { "id": 3, "title": "Song C", "artist": "Artist Z", "streams": 9500 },
    { "id": 4, "title": "Song D", "artist": "Artist W", "streams": 11000 },
    { "id": 5, "title": "Song E", "artist": "Artist V", "streams": 12500 },
    { "id": 6, "title": "Song F", "artist": "Artist U", "streams": 14000 },
    { "id": 7, "title": "Song G", "artist": "Artist T", "streams": 13000 },
    { "id": 8, "title": "Song H", "artist": "Artist S", "streams": 14500 },
    { "id": 9, "title": "Song I", "artist": "Artist R", "streams": 15000 },
    { "id": 10, "title": "Song J", "artist": "Artist Q", "streams": 16000 }
  ]
}


where I'm fetching my data from the json file using react-query
 const onError = (error) => {
    console.log("Error:", error);
  };
  const enabled = true;
  const endpoint = "totalStreamsData";
  const { data } = useFetchUsersData({ endpoint, enabled, onError });

import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:4000";

const fetchData = (endpoint) => {
  return axios.get(`${url}/${endpoint}`);
};

export const useFetchUsersData = ({
  endpoint,
  enabled,
  onSuccess,
  onError,
}) => {
  return useQuery("user", () => fetchData(endpoint), {
    enabled,
    onSuccess,
    onError,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: true,
    refetchIntervalInBackground: true,
  });
};



Your code doesn't show where you're passing in the endpoint to the useFetchUsersData custom hook.

It's there
The endpoint is passed as value of endpoint in the custom hook
Check const fetchData

Yea I know.. I'm asking where the endpoint value is being passed to the useFetchUsersData() hook in your component.

@HamedJimoh OP has const endpoint = "totalStreamsData";

What does this mean? "returns the first item of the object regardless of the one I'm trying to hit at"? It's not explained in the code, what are you returning from where?
